# Encoding grayscale/Gray16 image very slow compared to colored/Bgr32 image

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, encoding, jpeg

I'm encoding live images coming in, these are either Gray16 images or Bgr32 images.
I'm trying to lower the quality on the spot with the JPEGEncoding and saving the bytes to a memorystream for X amount of time.

The Bgr32 images are encoded in <2ms while the Gray16 images take around 20-30ms. I have tried all the default encoders(Jpeg, gif, png etc), they all give the same results.

Is this normal behaviors or is there something wrong? What could I improve?

```
using (MemoryStream oMemStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Before: " + oWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    JpegBitmapEncoder oEncoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    oEncoder.QualityLevel = 75;

    BtmapSource = BitmapSource.Create(640, 480, 96, 96, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Gray16, null, bPixels, 640 * System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Gray16.BitsPerPixel / 8);

    var BitmapFrame oFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(BtmapSource);
    oEncoder.Frames.Add(oFrame);
    oEncoder.Save(oMemStream);

    oWatch.Stop();

    Debug.WriteLine("After: " + oWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Comment: You probably pay for the gamma conversion.  Gray16 has a gamma of 1.0, Bgr32 uses the sRGB color space with a non-linear gamma that averages 2.2.  Matches the default color profile for JPEG.  Not something you can wish away.

Comment: That would make sense. Is there a way to not do the needed gamma conversion? Or a image format that has the a 1.0 gamma?